# Appium - Unable to Input Text to Field

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

I'm new to automation and having an issue with inputs. My current setup is testing an Android app using Robotframework and AppiumLibrary, and the application was written with Flutter. The issue is on the login widget for the app. I can click and tap the element for the email field fine using `xpath=//android.widget.EditText[@index='0']`, but when trying to input text it fails. Below is the appium stack trace for the failure. I have tried setting `unicodeKeyboard=true` with the same results. I know xpath is not ideal but I have nothing else for these elements other than the bounds, which I have also tried. Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

- Appium 1.18.3
- AndroidStudio 4.1
- Python 3.8
- RobotFramework 3.2.2

Appium Stack:

```
[W3C] Matched W3C error code 'invalid element state' to InvalidElementStateError
[W3C (3e5e357a)] Encountered internal error running command: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Cannot set the element to 'jmitchell+tedtedson@figure.com'. Did you interact with the correct element?
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.SendKeysToElement.setText(SendKeysToElement.java:88)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.SendKeysToElement.safeHandle(SendKeysToElement.java:119)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:41)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:253)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:247)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:68)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
[W3C (3e5e357a)]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: I think I may have found a work around for now. Added Process library to my .robot file and then using `run process  adb  shell  input text  ${USER}` worked.

Comment: Now the problem is that adb keeps missing characters.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter how the element is selected either. I even used the uiselector for uiautomator2 using the following and got the same result:                                 `${EMAIL}=  android=UiSelector().className("android.widget.EditText").index(0)`